# Recycleview in scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-recyclerview

I have created a fragment with scroll view which consist of recycle view in it. but the recycle view is not getting displayed in view please help me how to solve this, is there any other way to do this.

here is my layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"

        android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/productdetailpage_productimage"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"

        android:src="@drawable/product_image_menswear"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/floatingbutton"
            android:layout_marginTop="390dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="285dp"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shareicon"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/productdetailpage_share"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"

            android:background="@drawable/ic_share_grey600_18dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/productdetailpage_likebutton"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"

            android:background="@drawable/ic_favorite_outline_red_18dp"
           />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="47dp"
            android:text="likes(20)"
            android:textSize="10dp"/>


        <View
            android:id="@+id/productdetailpage_separator2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2px"
            android:layout_below="@+id/productdetailpage_productimage"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="#90909090"


            />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/productdetailpage_productname"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Burton Maroon Casual"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"

        android:layout_below="@+id/productdetailpage_separator2"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productdetailpage_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rs.3000"
            android:textColor="#FB8C00"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/productdetailpage_productname"
            />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/productdetailpage_separator3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2px"
            android:layout_below="@+id/productdetailpage_price"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="#90909090"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productdetailpage_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/productdetailpage_separator3"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Look uber trendy and cool wearing this maroon  coloured shirt from the house of Burton. Made of cotton, this printed shirt for men will keep you sweat free and comfortable all day long. This snazzy casual shirt will be a perfect addition to your wardrobe."
            />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/productdetailpage_separator4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2px"
            android:layout_below="@+id/productdetailpage_description"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="#90909090"
            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/availabestore_header"
            android:text="Available in 15 stores"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryColor"
            android:layout_below="@+id/productdetailpage_separator4"/>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/available_storeslist_productpage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/availabestore_header"
            ></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have scrolling views within a `ScrollView`, you need to use [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  ...
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best idea for performance, but if you really need it, you should use `NestedListView`, as @ianhanniballake says. Or try thу way discribed in [this blog](https://pristalovpavel.wordpress.com/2014/12/26/doing-it-right-vertical-scrollview-with-viewpager-and-listview/).